# InternalError: Graph execution error :Tensorflow Efficientdetd0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently attempting to perform transfer learning using the EfficientDet D0 model from the TensorFlow Applications module. My goal is to train this model on the Food101 dataset for object detection tasks. However, I am encountering an error whenever I try to run the code.

```
Saving TensorBoard log files to: training_logs/efficientnetb0_101_classes_all_data_feature_extract/20230627-212648
Epoch 1/3
2023-06-27 21:26:49.281247: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:561] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-06-27 21:26:49.281917: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1839] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:629 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-06-27 21:26:49.283370: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/llvm_gpu_backend/gpu_backend_lib.cc:561] libdevice is required by this HLO module but was not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
2023-06-27 21:26:49.283918: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1839] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:629 : INTERNAL: libdevice not found at ./libdevice.10.bc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 5
      1 # Turn off all warnings except for errors
      2 # tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
      3 
      4 # Fit the model with callbacks
----> 5 history_101_food_classes_feature_extract = model.fit(train_data,epochs=3,steps_per_epoch=len(train_data),validation_data=test_data,validation_steps=int(0.15 * len(test_data)),
      6                                                      callbacks=[create_tensorboard_callback("training_logs", 
      7                                                                                             "efficientnetb0_101_classes_all_data_feature_extract"),
      8                                                                 model_checkpoint])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InternalError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node cond_1/Adam/StatefulPartitionedCall defined at (most recent call last):
```

But its running fine of google colab, thats wierd. Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: I used to get multiple unexplained `GraphExecutionError`s. `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` solved the problem. You could try using this line after `import tensorflow as tf`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Dev Bhuyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12171892/dev-bhuyan) for his inputs, indeed it worked.Yet,adding more info for context.

The statement tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) in TensorFlow enables eager execution mode.

By default, TensorFlow uses a computational graph execution model, where operations are added to a graph and then executed in a session. Eager execution, on the other hand, allows operations to be executed immediately and returns results (which in my case solved certain graph implementation errors)

Reference:
[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/enable_eager_execution#:~:text=Eager%20execution%20provides%20an%20imperative,compat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/enable_eager_execution#:%7E:text=Eager%20execution%20provides%20an%20imperative,compat).